# How to use A* with the following map

Tags: algorithm, search, a-star

I'm developing a robot simulation using ROS and C++.

I have created a map, which is a list of free positions in a closed room like this one:

```
0.1,0;0.2,0;0.3,0;...
```

They are (x,y) locations separated by `;`. All of the locations in that list are the free locations in the map. If there is an obstacle in a location, that location won't be in list.

How can I use that list as a map for A* search algorithm?

I've thought to convert that list into a 2D matrix but I don't know what to put inside matrix's cell.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it sounds like you can simply convert the list into a 2D matrix by parsing the text file (set x to the character sequence before comma, skip comma, set y to the character sequence before semicolon, skip semicolon, convert x/y to numbers and update matrix accordingly using x/y as indices, etc.).

As for the matrix itself, consider simply a bird's-eye-view of the room, where a '0' in a cell represents a free space, while a '1' represents an obstacle (or the other way around; the values are arbitrary, as long as you use them consistently). And for the A* algorithm, any cell is essentially "adjacent" to the 4 neighboring cells (or whatever movement scheme you are using).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "character sequence"?

Comment: For example, in the above, you know that for the first coordinate, x has the value held in the string "0.1" and y has the value held in the string "0"; by doing parsing you can get these strings, then convert them to their actual number values.

Comment: Ok. So you are saying that I have to use x and y values as indices for the matrix, isn't it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the data to a graph (as in nodes and edges, not as in function plot). In order to do that, you not only need the positions, which translate to nodes (a.k.a. vertices) but the edges. There is an edge between two nodes when you can move from one node directly to the other. In other words, there is no node in between and also no obstacle preventing the movement. Once you have that part down, you can run the A* algorithm on the resulting graph easily.

Steps:

1. Read and parse input data.
2. Store data as list of nodes.
3. Define the requirements for an edge to exist between two nodes.
4. Create a list of edges with previously defined condition and the nodes.
5. Run A* on your graph.

Notes:

- I won't do the actual work for you because I guess its just homework. Nobody here will hopefully do that.
- You can solve each step on its own or even skip it and replace its results using hard-coded values.
- You can also skip generating the edges altogether. You just need to adjust the A* algorithm to generate the edges on demand on every node it visits. This may or may not be simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that I haven't found any implementation of A* to know which is its input. I guess that the input is a list of nodes and a list of edges. How do you define the edges?

Comment: What do you mean, you haven't found any implementation of A*? In any case, consider just starting with any graph theory tutorial, typical implementations of graphs are either using an adjacency list or an adjacency matrix and both types are usually discussed there.

Comment: Well, I have found this implementation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/.